# How to Filter Properties

Tags: lambda

I have `Institution` entities that have a `Fund` list as a property.

I have a List of allowed Funds separately.

I want to select Institutions which have any of the fund from `allowedFunds` list which can be done easily. But when I get Institutions I want the `Funds` list also to be filtered.

In other words I have `Institution1` with `Fund1` and `Fund2`. `Fund1` is also in  allowedFunds list. I want to return Institution1 with the `Funds` list having only Fund1. Is it possible to write a query for this with lambda expressions for EF 4.1?

```
    // I have allowed funds in a separate list
    IEnumerable<Fund> allowedFunds;

    public partial class Institution
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Fund> Funds { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Fund
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual Institution Institution { get; set; }
    }
```

Edit;
Oki,The question is edited and also here is another explanation. If you see the code below my 2nd comment(//remove not allowed Funds from institutions) that is what I want to do. but there I return Institute set and add the logic. Instead of doing that I want to return Institutions after removing not allowed funds.Below is my method. Thanks.

```
    public IEnumerable<Institution> FindInstitutionsForExternalUser(IEnumerable<Fund> allowedFunds)
    {
        IQueryable<Institution> query = GetObjectSet();
        //Institutions which are connected to allowedFunds
        if (allowedFunds != null)
        {
            IEnumerable<int> fundIds = allowedFunds.Select(fund => fund.Id);
            query = query.Where(i => i.Funds.Any(o => fundIds.Any(id => id == o.Id))); ;
        }
        IEnumerable<Institution> list = query.ToList().OrderBy(a => a.Name); 
        //remove not allowed Funds from institutions
        foreach (var institution in list)
        {
            IEnumerable<Fund> filterdFunds =
                institution.Funds.Where(fund => allowedFunds.Any(allowedFund => allowedFund.Id == fund.Id));
            institution.Funds = filterdFunds.ToList();
        }
        return list; 
    }
```

Comment: Wow, I can't follow what you are asking at all.  can you restructure your question?

Comment: Yes, Really hard to get the idea. Wht is your `allowedFunds` list ? Give some example and show how you have tried it .

Answer (score 0):

Try something like follows

```
from i in Institutes from f1 in i.Funds join f2 in AllowedFunds on f1.Id equals f2.Id select f1
```